# Module federation init script failing with error The "to" argument must be of type string. Received undefined

Tags: angular, webpack-module-federation

When I try to use the init script of the latest module federation plugin I get the error

> "The "to" argument must be of type string. Received undefined"

I pass in the project name and the port number and I am
using angular 15.1.0 and the plugin loaded is 15.0.3
anybody idea when this error occurs?

Answer (score 0):

Well after some investigation I found an existing bug which relates to your issue. As workaround you can do the following.

Goto node_modules > @angular-architects/module-federation/src/schematics/mf/schematics.js

Do this;

```
// changed this line
const relOutPath = path.relative(projectOutPath, outPath).replace(/\\/g, '/') + '/';

// to 
const relOutPath = path.relative(projectOutPath, outPath || '').replace(/\\/g, '/') + '/';
```

[link to issue](https://github.com/angular-architects/module-federation-plugin/issues/175)